# BadMethodCallException Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orderBy does not exist

Tags: laravel

Tengo dos tablas

La tabla activities

```
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name         | varchar(255)     | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| duration_act | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at   | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at   | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

y la tabla activitycategoryareas

```
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| id_activity       | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| id_category_areas | int(10) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| ans_act           | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| duration_act      | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at        | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at        | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

lo que quiero saber es, cuantas veces se utiliza una actividad en la tabla activitycategoryareas

para ellos hice lo siguiente

```
public function render()
{
    $activities = Activity::all();

    $activities = $activities->each( function ($activity) {
        $activity->count_activity = Activitycategoryarea::where('id_activity', $activity->id)->count();

    return view('livewire.activity.live-activity-table', compact('activities'));
}
```

y en la vista

```
               <table class="table table-striped table-hover card-table table-vcenter text-nowrap">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <div class="mt-3 h6">
                                    {{ __('id Activity') }}
                                </div>
                            </th>
                            <th >
                                <div class="mt-3 h6">
                                    {{ __('Name Activity') }}
                                </div>
                            </th>
                            <th >
                                <div class="mt-3 h6">
                                    {{ __('Uso') }}
                                </div>
                            </th>
                            <th scope="col" class="relative px-6 py-3">
                                <span class="sr-only">Edit</span>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    @if ($activities->count())
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach ($activities as $item)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <div>
                                            {{ $item->id }}
                                        </div>

                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div style="width: 350px; overflow: hidden; white-space: initial;">
                                            {{ $item->name }}
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div style="width: 350px; overflow: hidden; white-space: initial;">
                                            {{ $item->count_activity }}
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            @endforeach
                            <!-- More people... -->
                        </tbody>
                    @else
                        @livewire('component.live-search-footer')
                    @endif
                </table>
```

Del atributo **count_activity** estoy obteniendo la cantidad para mostrarlo en la columna **USO**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hasta hay todo va bien, el problema viene que intentar aplicar el buscador, paginación y orderBy

al cambiar en controlador en el **render** por esto

```
public function render()
{
    $activities = Activity::all();

    $activities = $activities->each( function ($activity) {
        $activity->count_activity = Activitycategoryarea::where('id_activity', $activity->id)->count();
    });

    return view('livewire.activity.live-activity-table',[
        'activities' => $activities
        ->where('name', 'like', "%{$this->search}%")
        ->orderBy($this->sort, $this->direction)
        ->paginate($this->perPage),
    ]);
}
```

me da el error

```
BadMethodCallException
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::orderBy does not exist.
```

No se como organizar el código para que me funcione

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El método `all()` perteneciente a la clase `Model` hace un retorno de:

> \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection|static[]

Dado eso si revisas dicha entidad ubicada en:

> *tuApp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection*

Podrás comprobar que efectivamente *el método `orderBy` no existe ahi*.

Ahora antes de sugerir el uso de algún método que pueda sustituir al actual que estas empleando, te haría las siguientes observaciones:

1. Estás cargando todos los registros de la tabla al hacer uso de `all()`, pero ¿para qué si al final los terminas filtrando y descartando X cantidad de ellos?
2. Tampoco es necesario considerar reasignar a la misma variable valores distintos, eso es confuso y puede llevar a errores producto de resultados un tanto inesperados

Dado lo anterior, propongo:

Paso 1.

Obtienes todos los registros una vez que cumplan las condiciones y realizas el paginate de los mismos

```
$activities = Activity::query()
                      ->where('name', 'like', "%{$this->search}%")
                      ->orderBy($this->sort, $this->direction)
                      ->paginate($this->perPage);
```

Paso 2.

Tomando dicho conjunto, procedes a iterarlos y agregar una nueva clave misma a la que le das un valor producto de otra consulta

```
$activities->each(function($item) {
    return $item->count_activity = Activitycategoryarea::where('id_activity', $item->id)->count();
});
```

Finalmente retornas tus resultados:

```
return view('livewire.activity.live-activity-table', compact('activities'));
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias....